# How to create MSBuild Link Task for C++ Modules

Tags: c++, msbuild, linker, c++20, c++-modules

## Question:

How would I create a minimalistic `MSBuild` project file, (`.props`), to define MSBuild Compile and Link tasks, from scratch, with `release` and `debug` targets for an MSVC C++20 project that uses Modules and Interfaces?

1. main.cpp
2. Module.ixx   (c++20 MSVC interface module).
3. SomeDependency.cpp
4. MSBuild.props  (***MSBuild project file from scratch*** that doesn't reference other .props files.)

[Microsoft's documentation for MSBuild's Link tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/link-task?view=vs-2022) doesn't seem to explain how to do this, especially with module definitions. I am especially looking for documentation on a minimalistic task definition that links with a C++20 module interface.

---

## Environment:

1. C++20
2. MSVC
3. MSBuild
4. WinRT
5. Visual Studio Code

Assuming most recent versions…

---

## Tried and failed:

**My non-MSBuild command file successfully linked with C++20 module interfaces:**

```
/interface /Tp Host.ixx
Engine.cpp
/reference Build\Debug\Host.ifc
/link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
../My.API/Build/Debug/pch.obj
```

**Pre-MSBuild, My VSCode CL task was a bit like:**

```
 "command": "cl.exe",
      "args": [
        "WindowsApp.lib",
        "/std:c++20",
        "/await",
        "/bigobj",
        "/utf-8",
        "/GL",
        "/Z7",
        "/EHsc",
        "/FC",
        "/Fd:",
        "Build/Debug/",
        "/Fo:",
        "Build/Debug/",
        "/Fe:",
        "Build/Debug/Engine.exe",
        "/ifcOutput",
        "Build/Debug/",
        "/Yupch.h",
        "/Fp../My.API/Build/Debug/pch.pch",
        "@Build/CL_CommandFile.txt"
      ]
```

---

**My Current Non-Linking MSBuild .props file:**

The compile tasks work to an extent, but very much a hack. The linking doesn't work whatsoever.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">    
    <ClCompile>  
      <!--
        
      -->
      <!--
        <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>        
        <UseCommonOutputDirectory>true</UseCommonOutputDirectory>
        <OutputPath>$(OutDir)</OutputPath>
        <BaseOutputPath>$(OutDir)</BaseOutputPath>    
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(OutDir)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
        
      -->
      <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
      <!-- Wraps cl.exe /Fo: Location/Name of .obj files. -->
      <ObjectFileName>$(OutDir)</ObjectFileName>    
      <!-- Output location for msbuild .tlg files. -->
      <TrackerLogDirectory>$(OutDir)</TrackerLogDirectory>
      
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <!-- Wraps cl.exe /I: Include path. -->
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>../My.API/Include<!--cl.exe /I--></AdditionalIncludeDirectories>      

      
      <!-- Wraps cl.exe /Yu: Name of precompiled header. -->
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
      <!-- Wraps cl.exe /Fp: Location of pch.pch -->
      <PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>../My.API/Build/Debug/pch.pch</PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>      
      <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>      
      <!-- Wraps cl.exe /Z7, no .pdb. otherwise Z7 or Zi -->
      <DebugInformationFormat>OldStyle</DebugInformationFormat>     
      <!-- Wraps stdcall, cdecl, etc. -->
      <CallingConvention>FastCall</CallingConvention>       
      <!-- Wraps cl.exe /MT, /MTd (debug), /MD (DLL)-->
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
      <!-- Wraps cl.exe /std:c++20 -->
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp20</LanguageStandard>
      <!-- Unwrapped cl.exe options: -->
      <AdditionalOptions>/permissive- /await /utf-8 /sdl /GL /EHsc /bigobj</AdditionalOptions>      
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>      
      <!--Wraps cl.exe /link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS: main(), or wWinMain() entry.  -->
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem> 
      <!--
      <AdditionalOptions>../My.API/Build/Debug/pch.obj</AdditionalOptions>      
      <AdditionalDependencies>../My.API/Build/Debug/pch.pch</AdditionalDependencies>      
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      -->      
      <ShowProgress>LinkVerbose</ShowProgress>     
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <!--
    <Link>      
    
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>      
      <AdditionalDependencies>SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS ../My.API/Build/Debug/pch.pch</AdditionalDependencies>          
    </Link>
    -->
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemGroup>    

  <!-- Files to compile: -->
  <ClCompile Include="ApplicationHost.ixx">    
    <!-- Where to put the .ifc output file. -->
    <AdditionalOptions>%(AdditionalOptions) /ifcOutput $(OutDir) /interface /Tp </AdditionalOptions>    
  </ClCompile>  
  <ClCompile Include="Engine.cpp">    
    <!-- Where to look for C++ module output .ifc file. -->
    <AdditionalOptions>%(AdditionalOptions) /reference $(OutDir)Host.ifc</AdditionalOptions>
  </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>

  </Project>
```

## Rephrase:

Could someone provide and/or explain MSBuild .props file Compile and Link tasks that incorporate C++20 modules and interfaces?  Hopefully with `release` and `debug` targets?